# How to migrate InfoPath XML Data to SQL Server?

Tags: 2013, infopath, xml, sql

The project is to create .net website forms using razor C# to replace Infopath.
Migrate the xml data on the sharepoint 2013 server to an SQL Server. My lead says to write a script; I think there are data tools that can do this, like Redhat or SMSS, SSIS that would help map the data to the tables, is that true? If so, what would they be?

I am not a sharepoint guru and I don't know anything about Infopath, but I am a seasoned programmer. Any ideas and help is truly appreciated, thanks. :)